# How to get commit details for a given repository and user using Bitbucket Java API

Tags: java, git, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I am developing a bitbucket plugin and for that I need to get the last committed date for a given repository by a given user. Is there anyway we can do that **without** using REST API?

I think we might be able to use ScmCommandFactory. But I could not find a good example on how to use it. I would really appreciate if someone could help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to find this? It's 5 years later and I still can't find any examples for this api: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/java-api/